# How does this method prevent optimizer stuck in local minima?

Tags: deep-learning

I am reading [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337401161_Fundamental_Concepts_of_Convolutional_Neural_Network) and came across this section. I am not able to understand how or intuitively see how the formula help to overcome optimizer stuck in local minima. Please explain how it works.

[image]

Comment: The answers to [What is momentum in neural network?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/84167/135707) provide some good explanations of momentum, as well as references for further reading.

Comment: Thanks for the link and mention the keyword "momentum". I found a more sensible explanation. This is what I'm actually looking for https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457212/how-does-stochastic-gradient-descent-with-momentum-distinguish-between-local-min .